# How to extract possible actions with an effect on the current website using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I would like to get all actions with some kind of effect to the current website.
By effect I mean changing the current website, leading to a different website, popups etc. so basically the visual stuff.
I know that it is probably hard to restrict these actions since many different actions can have different effects to website.
Therefore, I will have to filter for all input elements such as tags "a", "button" etc.
Besides, I will have to search for all registered event listeners in JavaScript.

Is there a library or an easier way to extract such possible actions or maybe an easier way?

The possible actions are required to determine which actions have not been used yet in my existing tests.